# Upload Device Information to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I would like to submit information about the device in my iphone application. i.e what device is using the application and the date. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me/point me towards how I can upload this information via php to my MySQL database hosted on my website. I would also need to know how to set up this database assumably via php too so that the columns would contain the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cooking up your own implementation, have you thought of using something like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/)? Besides the things you listed above that you'd like to track, Flurry helps you track other useful data. Another analytics service to consider is [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/) (though it seems a bit rough right now...).

Hope this helps!